# SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2008 no longer able to connect to remote servers (other methods work)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've had SSMS 2008 installed for quite some time and been able to connect to remote servers without issue.

Recently, I installed Toad for Oracle, and after restarting, SSMS now hangs when trying to connect to any servers I normally connect to. (I don't know if Toad caused the problem, but thought I'd mention it, seems too coincidental)

- I've tried pinging the servers from my computer and it works fine.
- ODBC connections to the servers works fine.
- I've downloaded HeidiSQL to test the server connections and it works fine.
- Within SSMS, I've tried the Import/Export Wizard and it also is able to connect fine.

The problem seems to be strictly with Management Studio. I've uninstalled and reinstalled and the issue persists. I also tried updating/repairing .Net versions 2, 3.5 and 4

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have the option to uninstall Toad to see If SSMS works?

Comment: It's better also to add `sql-server` tag for questions concerning any version of the server. As for your question, problems frequently happens with ssms as long as you install smth on your PC. But I've always found solutions in google. Good luck ;)

Comment: Toad seems to install some plugin with ssms. That might be causing issues. http://documents.software.dell.com/DOC95065. Did you check event log to see any potential errors. https://support.software.dell.com/toad-for-sql-server/kb/118695